Playwright and AG Grids using typescript
Newbie here.... i am a QA and writing automation tests using Playwright,Typescript and Cucumber.
I am testing to ensure i can create a project and then see it on a project list screen on the front end.
I have managed to log in and create the project. The problem lies where my project is now listed on an AG Grid and i am unsure how to write tests for this, as my project will always change positions on the list.
Has anyone any experience on this and could try and tell me how to tackle it?
Should add I don't have a huge amount of automation knowledge but trying to learn.
Thanks in advance.

Can your test filter down the grid results so what you are looking for is always the first/only row displayed?

Thanks Andy, i actually think i have got it by searching for it using by getByTitle which seems to be working for now! thanks so much for your response.
